# socket exception while running SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting this error when I run npm run sonar for analyzing my nodejs code.

```
ERROR: Failed to get response while analyzing file:///newvolume/MTP/staging/mt_cloudplatform/backend/src/app/controllers/mockTestBookmarkController.js
java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
        at okhttp3.RealCall.timeoutExit(RealCall.java:108)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:97)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.call(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:159)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBasedRulesSensor.analyze(EslintBasedRulesSensor.java:124)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBasedRulesSensor.execute(EslintBasedRulesSensor.java:100)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:400)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:395)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:358)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:358)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:230)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:202)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:101)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:264)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

It was working fine earlier but now I am getting this error. What could be the issue?
I used this tutorial for setting up sonarqube,
https://arjunphp.com/how-to-integrate-sonar-for-a-node-js-project/

Comment: It looks like a plugin using JsLint has some problems while analysing the file mentioned. Have you changed something in that file? Try to analyse this file by hand first.

Answer (score 0):

I found that increasing available memory for Scanner may help, on GitHub issue page. It was sufficient in my case. Add this line with extended memory limit to your sonar-scanner.properties file

```
sonar.javascript.node.maxspace=4096
```

As typescripts dependencies are blamed as part of the reason for the timeout you may try uninstall some dependencies before scanning.
Link to original [issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/1835)